How Determine the set of efficient extreme points using the parameterization?
I am writing to you because I need you to explain the solution to this exercise. I am very sorry, I have not found anything that will help me solve it. I know that in this forum there are teachers with a fairly advanced level and I trust that I can find help.
For the problem: Max. f(x) subject to $x\in{}X, where: \\X = \{ x\in{}\Bbb R^3 | 4x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 \leq 100, x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 600, x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0\}\\ f = (f_1, f_2), f_1(x) = 4x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3, f_2(x) = x_2 + x_3$

Determine the set of efficient extreme points using the parameterization method. 2) Determine the set of efficient points.

This exercise is optimization.
To find the efficient extreme points, we first need to find the extreme points of the set X. To do this, we equate the constraints to the corresponding equations:
4x1 + 2x2 + x3 = 100
x1 + x2 + x3 = 600
Solving this system of equations, we obtain the extreme points of the set X:
x1 = 200, x2 = 200, x3 = 200
x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 600
x1 = 0, x2 = 300, x3 = 300
Now we are going to parameterize the objective functions f1 and f2 with respect to a parameter t:
f1(x) = 4x1 + 3x2 + x3
f2(x) = x2 + x3
We substitute the values of the extreme points into the objective functions:
For the point (200, 200, 200):
f1(t) = 4(200) + 3(200) + (200) = 1400
f2(t) = (200) + (200) = 400
For the point (0, 0, 600):
f1(t) = 4(0) + 3(0) + (600) = 600
f2(t) = (0) + (600) = 600
For the point (0, 300, 300):
f1(t) = 4(0) + 3(300) + (300) =1200
f2(t) =(300)+(300)=600
Therefore, the efficient endpoints are:
(200,200,200)
(0,300,300)
Step 2: Determine the set of efficient points.
To determine the set of efficient points, we compare the solutions obtained in the previous step with respect to efficiency. In this case, we see that the point (200,200,200) is more efficient than the point (0,300,300), since it has a larger value in both objective functions.
Therefore, the set of efficient points is given by:
{(200,200,200)}

It is fairly obvious that $X$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb R^3$.  So I'm familiar with the notion of extreme points.  However I don't know what is meant by "efficient" points or extreme points.  You should provide more context for this exercise.

I have added the resolution of the exercise but I don't know if it is correct, can you help me with the correct solution?

I would need a definition of "efficient point" and/or "efficient extreme point".  Perhaps you can name the textbook or other resource where you found this exercise so that the definition is given here, at least by reference.
